# How should i define something constantlike in Erlang

Tags: erlang, magic-numbers

I have a module which does some non constrained minimization. I'd like to keep its' interface as simple as possible, so the best choice would be to reduce it to a single function something like: min_of( F ).

But as soon as it is brutal computation, i would have to deal with at least two constants: precision of minimization algorithm and maximum number of iterations, so it would not hang itself if target function doesn't have local minimum at all.

Anyways, the next best choice is: min_of( F, Iterations, Eps ). It's ok, but I don't like it. I would like to still have another min_of( F ) defined something like this:

```
min_of( F ) ->
    min_of( F, 10000, 0.0001).
```

But without magic numbers.

I'm new to Erlang, so I don't know how to deal with this properly. Should i define a macros, a variable or maybe a function returning a constant? Or even something else? I found Erlang quite expressive, so this question seems to be more of a good practice, than technical question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can define macros like this

```
-define(ITERATIONS, 10000).
-define(EPS, 0.0001).
```

and then use them as

```
min_of(F, ?ITERATIONS, ?EPS).
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use macros but you can also use in-lined functions.

```
-compile({inline, [iterations/0, eps/0]}).

iterations() -> 10000.
eps() -> 0.0001.
```

and then use it in the way

```
min_of(F) ->
  min_of(F, iterations(), eps()).
```

The benefit is you can use all syntax tools without need of `epp`. In this case also calling of function is not performance critical so you can even go without `inline` directive.